# opengl rotate by quaternion

Tags: opengl, rotation

I implemented my quaternion class like [this](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/math-and-physics/quaternion-powers-r1095). I can convert the quaternion to 3x3 rotation matrix, but then how should i apply that to my modelview matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

glMultMatrixf(GLfloat*) and glMultMatrixd(GLdouble*) do exactly what you need. The only thing is to convert 3x3 matrix (O) to 4x4 matrix (O') by adding some 0 and 1:

```
     |       0|
O' = |   O   0|
     |       0|
     | 0 0 0 1|
```

Note that openGL stores matrices in column-major order (like in Fortran).